# Does django connection cursor auto commit after each .execute() query?

Tags: django, connection, database-cursor

```
from django.db import connection

def executeQuery(query, params):
    cur=connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(query, params) // this is update query
    cur.close()
```

I have series of queries and I call this method for each query, but it looks like it rollbacks entire operation if any query (let's say 3rd query) gets failed.

I thought, after `execute()`, it immediately commit it and it does not depend on the next query.

Shouldn't django has auto commit feature?

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: What DB backend are you using?

Comment: django 1.5 and DB is mssql..

Answer (score 5):

Database altering operations are automatically committed. However, if you are using the `django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware` or something similar, then they will be only committed if the page rendering finishes without any error, otherwise a rollback will happen.

For further details refer to the [documentation](https://django-doc-test1.readthedocs.io/en/stable-1.5.x/topics/db/transactions.html) for django 1.5 (the version used in the question). Check the latest [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/) too.

Comment: Yes I am using django middleware. But inside my view function I call executeQuery() function for each query and this executeQuery() has try -catch. So I always catch an error and send error message back to the end user. So I suppose as executeQuery() gets call for each query, it should commit it once it exits (for each query).

Comment: Then https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.autocommit is your friend

Comment: I know @transaction.commit_on_success will work. But when I was using django 1.4, I didn't need to use this decorator and then I switched to django 1.5 and suddenly I seems like my view function start rollback entire transaction if it fails.

Comment: But in django 1.4 it committed whatever query executed before it gets failed. I want to find out answer of "why it rollbacks in django 1.5 and not in django 1.4"??